# Ensure @web alias is explicitly overridden

Tags: craft3, alias

I just stumbled upon this advice in my Craft3-system report:

*"Ensure @web alias is explicitly overridden"*

In which file do I need to put the override? "config/general.php" doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aliases can be defined and/or overridden using the [`aliases`](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#aliases) config setting from your `config/general.php` file.

Assuming you have your site URL set to an environment variable `PRIMARY_SITE_URL` or similar:

```php
use craft\helpers\App;

return [
    ...
    'aliases' => [
        '@web' => App::env('PRIMARY_SITE_URL'),
    ],
];
```

This is also referenced in the official docs [here](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/#aliases).

Comment: Great! I got it working, using your syntax. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Just for additional context as it's a little buried in the docs, the recommendation of explicitly setting the @web alias is mainly around protecting against a potential cache poisoning attack vector. By setting this alias you are ensuring only a specific site URL can be returned.

Answer (score 5):

## Update for Craft CMS V4

**Note**: *You can still use the 'older' V3 syntax in V4, see the comment below.*

---

For version four, the syntax for general config has changed.
[See the docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/config/general.html#system)

```php
// config/general.php

return GeneralConfig::create()
    ...
    // Set aliases
    ->aliases([
        '@web' => App::env('PRIMARY_SITE_URL'),
    ])
;
```

*For V3, use [the accepted answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/39347/13762) by Mats Mikkel Rummelhoff*

Comment: Technically, the old (array) syntax still works in Craft 4 and there are no plans to remove it from future Craft versions – but the new, "fluent" syntax outlined here is the one Pixel & Tonic is promoting currently :)

Comment: @MatsMikkelRummelhoff Ah, that makes sense. I'm relatively new to Craft and noticed the syntax in the default templates that got created were different to any shown here. I'll update the answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In case of multi-environment config,
You must paste the Mats's answer into '*' key (config/general.php), like this:

```
return [
    '*' => [
        'aliases' => [
            '@web' => App::env('PRIMARY_SITE_URL'),
        ],
        ...
    ],
];
```

I had to read the core to found how silly is this undocumented setting!